# Can a file be closed in vim without exiting?

Tags: vim

I have a file open in `vim`, and I have finished my edits. Is there a way for me to close the file (or *buffer*) so that the `vim` screen is blank?

Comment: Related network: [vi.se].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That would be `:bd`. `:help :bd` in vim 8.2 gives:

> ```
> :[N]bd[elete][!]                        *:bd* *:bdel* *:bdelete* *E516*
> :bd[elete][!] [N]
>             Unload buffer [N] (default: current buffer) and delete it from
>             the buffer list.  If the buffer was changed, this fails,
>             unless when [!] is specified, in which case changes are lost.
>             The file remains unaffected.  Any windows for this buffer are
>             closed.  If buffer [N] is the current buffer, another buffer
>             will be displayed instead.  This is the most recent entry in
>             the jump list that points into a loaded buffer.
>             Actually, the buffer isn't completely deleted, it is removed
>             from the buffer list |unlisted-buffer| and option values,
>             variables and mappings/abbreviations for the buffer are
>             cleared. Examples:
>                 :.,$-bdelete    " delete buffers from the current one to
>                                 " last but one
>                 :%bdelete       " delete all buffers
> ```

Comment: There’s a bit of a terminology mismatch: files aren’t “open” in Vim. (Buffers are loaded.) So this achieves the goal, but it might be worth pointing out the distinction, esp. since the buffer abstraction is useful for many kinds of editing techniques.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: ? ... but *ultimately*, isn't a file closed?

Comment: @Seamus the file, when there is one, is not kept open while editing. So no, it does not get closed.

Comment: @Olivier: so, IOW, the file is actually closed immediately after it's opened - *before* any editing takes place?

Comment: @Seamus in practice, yes, Vim doesn't keep the handle open for the file being edited (you can run `ls /proc/<vim-pid>/fd -l` to check, you'll see it has a swapfile open for that file, but not the file itself)

Comment: Or not even a swapfile, if you've disabled those (as I do).

Comment: @D.BenKnoble while it's true that editors generally don't have a *file descriptor* opened on the file except when they load it (or sections thereof for those that don't load them full in memory) or save it (and whether they do or not is more of an implementation detail), the file can still be considered as opened by the editor by some (common) definition of *open* like when you say you open a pdf file in `evince` or an image file in an image viewer. That's how I understood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add a few more ideas and try to address some questions of terminology.

- Vim doesn't manipulate files directly very often. Commands like `:edit` read a file into a buffer. The buffer and file share a connection only by virtue of the fact that the buffer's name is that of the file; changes to the underlying file are not automatically reflected to the buffer and vice-versa. Commands like `:write` write a buffer to a file—*any* buffer (the current one) to *any* file. The default is the name of the buffer, but can be overridden. And, some buffers have no name! (See `:help backup` for other file operations that may happen when you write a file.)
- On the flip side, Vim does usually maintain a swap file. This has several different purposes, but one is to warn about simultaneous edits by marking that a particular Vim instance "owns" the file. (The readonly `view` doesn't need to care about swapfiles until you try to edit the file.)

So there are at least a couple of ways to interpret the question:

1. How do I tell Vim I'm done with a file so that other Vims could edit it? In that case, you probably do want `:bdelete`, which deletes the buffer and as a side-effect causes the swapfile to be deleted. You might consider just quitting altogether, though. If startup time is fast, it's easier to jump in and out of Vim than try to maintain a long running session (though cf. `:help :mksession` and `:help -S`).
2. How do I blank the screen? You probably just want `:enew`, which is kind of like the buffer you get if you run Vim with no arguments.

Comment: Thanks - the `:enew` operator also works.  Offhand I can't think of a situation where I'd need it over `bd`, but I'm relatively new to `vim`.

Comment: I generally prefer to not have to “manage” my buffers by deleting them. Leaving them around also benefits you when using `:buffer`, `:sbuffer`, completion, etc.

Comment: Maybe I'll get to that point eventually. :)